# Map not covering -Test Class in Salesforce

Tags: apex, code-coverage

```
  public static void insertLogicHandler(List<Task> listNewTasks, Map<Id, Task> mapNewTasks, String context){
        List<Task> listTasks = mapNewTasks.values();
        Map<Id, Task> mapFlowTasks = new Map<Id, Task>();

        //business logic to create sub-Maps that are passed into specific methods
        for(Task t: listTasks){
            System.debug('#### in TaskTrigger_Handler.insertLogicHandler for loop');
            if(t.WhoId != null && t.Type != 'Campaign Email'){
                mapFlowTasks.put(t.Id, t);//This line is not covering 
            }
}
```

I have created the task dummy records ,while assigning who id as contact.id,I'm encountering flow exception.Could anyone help me with covering the Map?

Comment: welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] for getting the most from the community. In particular, use [edit] and show your testmethod

Comment: Can you paste the test method for it/ test data you created?